# How to make these rails routs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm trying to make some routes to view and manage missions in an app.
The missions belong to organizations. 
My idea is to do something like this:

```
organizations/1/missons                 #(index) list of missions of the organization
organizations/1/missions/1                  #show a mission that belongs to an organization
organizations/1/admin/missions              #list of missions in a new view that has the commands to admin the missions
organizations/1/admin/missions/1/edit         #edit the mission
organizations/1/admin/missions/1/destroy    #destroy the mission
missions                                    #all missions of all organizations
missions/1                                  #show mission page
```

I don't really know if this is a good way to rout a system like this or if it's overkill in a way.
For now I have the standard routing working:

```
resources :organizations do
    resources :missions
end
```

But I wish to have some more views.
What's the best way to route this, and how many controllers to keep them lean and with few actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always there are several ways to accomplish this. I would probably go with two different controllers for the regular missions, perhaps like this:

```
resources :organizations do
  resources :missions, :only => [:index, :show]
  resources :admin_missions
end
resources :missions, :only => [:index, :show]
```

This would of course result in "...admin_missions..." instead of "...admin/missions..." but I think it is the easiest way to do it. This will use three controllers where MissionsController is called from two different locations but you can check what to display by checking if the params[:organization_id] is present or not.

### Edit

If you decide to use the same controller for all missions and for organizations, here is an example for how the index action could start:

```
def index
  if params[:organization_id]
    @organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])
    @missions = @organization.missions.all
  else
    @missions = Mission.all
  end

  ...
end
```

But if you want to have different views for them, then it might be better to separate to two controllers.

Comment: Hello Danne, thanks for your help. I've been reading on the subject, but it's still isn't very clear. Your solution seems pretty good, but having the nested resources :missions and the resources :missions makes me do some logic in the controllers that I don't really like. For example, in the nested I always want to index missions in the organization scope. Outside, I want to show for all organizations and implement search options. Maybe it's better another controller, so I can handle each case on it's own?

Comment: Of course, it might be more clear to do different controllers, but it is not that difficult to test for organization. I'll add an example to my answer just to show one way to do it.

Comment: Thank you, I will go for your approach since it's fast and keeps me going.

Comment: I'm stuck :( The new action in the admin_Controller sends me to the form, but after the submit the create action is never called. Instead I see this on the console:
Started POST "/organizations/1/missions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-03-13 14:44:13 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/organizations/1/missions"):

But it's even weirder because the index action of the mission controller is also never called, and that route does exist, because if I press enter, the index page is rendered.

Comment: Maybe the form is wrong and dosn't point to the right route? 
<%= semantic_form_for [@organization, @mission] do |form|%>

Comment: The reason that the index action is not called is because the form submits with the POST protocol and index only responds to GET. And the reason that it submits to missions in the first place instead of admin_missions is because it tries to automatically set the url based on the model name. However, that can be overridden like this: <%= form_for @mission, :url => organization_admin_missions_path(@organization) do |form| %>

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been struggling with this and just found out the way to do it trough Rails 3 Way book. I was going to post it here and found your comment. It was hidden so I didn't saw it earlier. But thanks a lot for your time!